# Multiple Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'd like to know when exactly we have the right to inverse the order of the variables in a multiple integral. Which are the cases which cause problems. (When $\int_a^b \int_c^d \int_e^f f(x,y,z) \, \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dz \neq \int_c^d \int_a^b \int_e^f f(x,y,z) \, \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dz \, \mathrm dy$ ??).

And when we have the right to do it what changes we have to do in the function?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the integral matters in cases where the integral of the absolute value is not finite; this is equivalent to [Lebesgue integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integral).

Comment: And if it's not infinite we always can switch the order?

Comment: @TheAnswer our integral must converge absolutely for Fubini's theorem to hold. If it does, then we may safely change the order of integration.